# Can i develop IOS app and mobile sw on windows pc or must I buy a mac?

Tags: android, ios, macos, windows-8, windows-phone-7.1.1

i wanna develop ios programming and also other mobile programming so i think about buying a mac. But they are expensive for me and other pc's that have more ram and better processor are chipper than mac. So do you think, can i develop ios in a virtual machine. I heard that this situation is a bit difficult because all pc's couldn't handle it. The pc that i want to buy have with windows 8:

- 16 GB RAM, DDR3, Intel Core i7 3632QM, 2,20 GHz, 2 GB Nvidia GT630M Optimus

On the other hand, the mac has these properties:

- APPLE MACBOOKPRO, CORE İ5 3210M, 2.5GHZ-4GB DDR3-500 GB-CAM-BT-MCX LION, 13.3"- Intel Graphics 4000

So, which one is the best for developing ios, android and windows phone ?

Comment: You can't do iOS from Windows so the mac is your only option ... rubbish spec by comparison to the windows pc though :(

Comment: not a valid question for stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS development must be done under OS X. The proper way to do this is to buy Mac hardware. You can build a [Hackintosh](http://www.hackintosh.com/) if you'd rather, but you cannot install OS X in a virtual machine.

What you could do, if you want to target multiple platforms (Windows Phone, iOS, Android) is to use a cross-platform development tool. You may (I haven't checked) find one that runs under Windows and will compile for iOS. You still have the problem of uploading to the App Store however, as that process is now integrated into Xcode (Apple's development environment).

Comment: You can install OS X in a virtual machine

Comment: @jcesar got a link? Last I heard it was not permitted by Apple's licence agreement for OS X, but then neither is building a hackintosh.

Comment: it's not permitted by Apple, and hackintosh neither. http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/07/mountain-lion-virtualbox.html

Answer (score 1):

I bet you could pull it of SOMEHOW on windows.. I mean .. in THEORY :) [rebuilt the compiler, copy the headers and redo the device drivers]

**but in reality you cannot do it without osx**

Answer (score 0):

You can install osx on a virtual machine but afaik it's not legal.

Also you can use some cross-platform mobile sdk like [Marmalde](https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/), develop on Windows/Visual Studio and buy a cheap Macbook or Mac Mini for testing/publishing to appstore.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that if you buy some old Mac, it may not work with SDK. It reqiures Intel cpu, old PowerPc's are not supported.
And don't even try to install iAtkos on VirtualBox, cause it's illegal.